# problem with prevent and continue submit form after ajax execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have form with select. If select value is equal to 2 then part of form is sendign asynch via ajax and later the rest of the form should be sending via POST function. My problem is when I click submit ajax execution is performs correctly but POST method stuck, nothing happens. It looks like be page refresh.
My code

```js
 $('form').submit(function(e) {
            if($('#car_type').val() == 2)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;

                    var type = $('#new_type').val();
                    var number = $('#numer').val();                    
                    var form = $(this);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ url('cars/type') }}",
                        method: "POST",
                        context: form,
                        data: {type: type, number: number, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},

                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.result > 0) {                                
                            } else {
                                $("#msg").html("Errors, try again later!");
                                $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            this.off('submit');                      
                            this.submit();
                        }
                    })

            }
        });
```

Comment: You are doing `this.submit()` in the `complete` callback. That is probably why your page refreshes.

Comment: Ok, but when `this.submit()` is in `success` it's like it press submit button again. I have confirm on sumbit so it's asking twice.... and nothings happen.

Comment: It depends on the rest of your code. Since there is no way to see whether your `form` is right, anything can be wrong there, or somewhere else.